# Inverse drift SDE solution

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Does the following SDE have a solution:

$$ dX_t = \frac{dt}{X_t}+W_t $$

where $W_t$ is a Brownian Motion, with initial state $X_0$?

I have tried applying Ito's lemma to $X_t^2$:

$$ dX_t^2 =  3dt + 2X_tdW_t $$

But I am again blocked.

Comment: Bessel Process: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_process
Also: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~lawler/bessel.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the links @AlexR.